# Got their wires crossed.

Tags: meaning-in-context

Regarding a policy meeting I read:

*the meeting was a complete disaster, all members got their wires crossed before everybody left.*

Does it mean that they quarrelled and came to blows?

Comment: [General Reference](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/get-your-wires-crossed) *When people get their wires crossed, they have a different understanding of the same situation*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it means they misunderstood each other.

It probably comes from a telephone switchboard analogy. Once, operators had to manually connect two parties with wires. If they put the wires into the wrong plugs, people would think they were talking one party (person) but actually be talking to another. This would cause misunderstandings, as they would be talking about different things. Hence, their "wires were crossed".

If I say now: "We got our wires crossed," it means I thought we were talking about one thing, but the person I was talking to thought the subject was something entirely different.

So in your example, the people at the meeting had different understandings of the agenda; they were discussing different things and obviously getting nowhere in arriving at decisions. It would have been frustrating, but there is no indication in that sentence that they actually came to blows. There is no violence implied, or even real hostility...just, as I said, misunderstanding.

(And haven't we all been in meetings like that at one time or another? lol)

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily came to blows, but rather they couldn't agree on what they were discussing.

**[English definition of “get your wires crossed”](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/get-your-wires-crossed)**

> get your wires crossed
>
> When people get their wires crossed, they have a different understanding of the same situation:
>
> e.g. Somehow we got our wires crossed because I'd got the 23rd written down in my diary and Jen had the 16th.

Answer (score -1):

The confusion may be based on the definition of **cross wires**: Not accordant with what is wished or expected;
      interrupting; adverse; contrary; thwarting; perverse. "A
      cross fortune." --Jer. Taylor.
      [1913 Webster]